# How to select only info start with pattern in a column and print in another one

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a data file `A.tsv` (field separator = `\t`) :

```
id  clade   mutation
243 40A S:ojo,L:juju,S:lili
254     
267 40B J:jijy,S:asel,M:ase
```

And I want to print in another column (in a new file `B.tsv`) only mutation that start with `S:`, like this :

```
id  clade   mutation    S_mutation
243 40A S:ojo,L:juju,S:lili S:ojo,S:lili
254     
267 40B J:jijy,S:asel,M:ase S:asel
```

I tried some command with awk with no result :

```
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } NR==1 {$(NF+1)="S_Mutation"} ; NR != 1 { $4 = ($3==^[Ss] ? $4 ) }; 1' A.tsv > B.tsv
```

Do you have an idea how to do that ? Thanks

Comment: Is it correct that you don't want a comma separating the added columns from the originals?

Comment: Yes the Field separator of my file is a tab (\t).All the column including the new one needs do be tab-separated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `POSIX awk`, we can do as shown.
Split the third fied on comma for rows >1 and select those elements that begin with S: and then join them with comma, and make it the last+1 field.

```
awk -F '\t' '
  BEGIN {
    OFS = FS
    _SEP_ = ","
  }

  NR==1{$(NF+1) = "S_mutation"}

  NR>1&&length($3)>0{
    nf = split($3, a, _SEP_)
    t = ""
    for (i=1; i<=nf; i++) {
      if (a[i] ~ /^S:/) {
        t = t (t=="" ? t : _SEP_) a[i]
      }
    }
    $(NF+1) = t
  }1
' file
```

---

Same thing in `Perl` but with the  use of regexes

```
perl -lnse '$,="\t";
  print $_,($.==1?q(S_mutation):
  "@{[/(?:\t|,)\KS:[^,]*/g]}"||());
' -- -\"=, ./file
```

---

Output:

```
id   clade  mutation             S-mutation
243  40A    S:ojo,L:juju,S:lili  S:ojo,S:lili
254                              
267  40B    J:jijy,S:asel,M:ase  S:asel
```

Comment: instead of setting `$(NF+1)` that it's squeezing consecutive Tabs into one (for example in line 4th of the OP's sample data), you can do ` print $0, (NR==1?"S_mutation":t)` and so you need to remove the idiom `1` plus  `NR==1{$(NF+1) = "S_mutation"}` and `$(NF+1) = t` parts then

Comment: Thanks for the tip! will try to incorporate it in the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk` (POSIX).

```c
awk -F "\t" '
BEGIN   { OFS = FS }
NR == 1 { $4 = "S_Mutation" }
NR  > 1 && NF == 3 {
    printf "%s", $0 "\t"
    $0 = $3
    gsub(/[^S]:[^,]*,?/, "")
    sub(/,$/, "")
    print $1
    next
}
1' data.txt
```

- If line is > 1 and number of fields = 3

  - Print line, without trailing newline
  - Set line = field 3
  - Remove strings not starting with `S:`
  - Remove any trailing comma
  - Print field with newline
  - Process next line
- Else

  - Print line

You might want to not print trailing tab, test if `$1` is anything after substitution and then print `TAB` + field. (In case you do not want trailing tabs on lines where there are no `S:xxx` fields. Something like:

```c
    # Print line
    printf "%s", $0
    # Set line = field 3
    $0 = $3
    # Replace all N:xxx where N is not S
    gsub(/[^S]:[^,]*,?/, "")
    # Remove trailing comma
    sub(/,$/, "")
    # Print the field
    if ($1 != "")
        print "\t"$1
    else
        print ""
    # Continue with next line
    next
```

Answer (score 2):

With Perl

```
perl -F'\t' -lpe '
    push @F, $. == 1 ? "S_mutation" : join ",", grep { /^S:/ } split /,/, $F[2];
    $_ = join "\t", @F
' A.tsv > B.tsv
```

Ex.

```
$ perl -F'\t' -lpe '
    push @F, $. == 1 ? "S_mutation" : join ",", grep { /^S:/ } split /,/, $F[2];
    $_ = join "\t", @F
' A.tsv | column -t
id   clade  mutation             S_mutation
243  40A    S:ojo,L:juju,S:lili  S:ojo,S:lili
254
267  40B    J:jijy,S:asel,M:ase  S:asel
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
{ c3=$3; gsub(/(^|,)[^S]*(,|$)/, ",", c3); gsub(/^,+|,+$/, "", c3)
  print $0, (NR==1?"S_Mutation":c3)
}' infile
```

FS is the input field separator and OFS is the output field separator; both we set to a Tab `\t` character; then we took a backup from the 3<sup>rd</sup> field by `c3=$3` for doing substitution on that and keep original intact.

then the first gsub() function replaces those sub-fields (which they are delimited with a comma character) with a comma that if that is not started with `S` char; second gsub() removes the leading(`^,+`)/trailing(`,+$`) comma(s) that they may appear after some removal.

then we print the entire line followed by the final value of the variable `c3` or `S_Mutation` string if it was the first line that ternary operator (*`condition?if-true:if-false`*) controls that which to print when condition met.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using `sed`:

```
sed 'h;s/.*[[:space:]]/,/;s/,[^S]:[^,]*//g;x;G;s/\n,/\t/'
```

Please note that `\t` will only work with GNU `sed`. For other flavours, insert a literal tab, usually by entering <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> and then the tab key.

The concept is to save the line in the hold space, then to isolate the last column and remove all mutations except for the `S:` ones. Then append this as the last column to the saved line:

- `h` copies the line to the hold space
- `s/.*[[:space:]]/,/` replaces everything upto the last tab or whitespace by a comma, so the last column remains, prepended by a comma. This comma will help in the next step
- `s/,[^S]:[^,]*//g` removes all elements except the `S:` ones
- `x` exchanges hold space and pattern space, so `G` will append the new column to the original one kept in hold space
- `s/\n,/\t/` finally replaces the newline from appending and the comma we introduced by a tab